# Caliburn Micro Capture Mouse Position

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am new to Caliburn Micro and trying to capture mouse position whenever left button is up on a Viewport3D control.

Using this in XAML;

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseLeftButtonUp] = [Action MouseUp($eventArgs, $source)]
```

and that in ViewModel:

```
public void MouseUp(MouseEventArgs args, IInputElement elem)
{
    Point pt = args.GetPosition(elem);
    //do something with pt
}
```

I can get mouse hit position. However, what I would like to have in ViewModel is something like:

```
public void MouseUp(Point pt)
{
    // do something with pt
}
```

I do not want to have IInputElement parameters etc. in my ViewModel -- the event is raised by Viewport so it should be considered as the IInputElement.

Can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this. What you want to do is to use MessageBinder.SpecialValues to create your own special value that will parse the point and return that instead.

So where you are setting up Caliburn.Micro, add the following code:

```
        MessageBinder.SpecialValues.Add("$mousepoint", ctx =>
        {
            var e = ctx.EventArgs as MouseEventArgs;
            if (e == null)
                return null;

            return e.GetPosition(ctx.Source);
        });
```

Then you can use it in Message.Attach like this:

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseLeftButtonUp] = [Action MouseUp($mousepoint)]
```

There you go, cleaner ViewModel :).

Comment: Just remember to make sure your special values parameter name is in lowercase or you could run into parameter passing issues!